# How to generate with openSSL a key pair + CSR with a custom field name and value?

Tags: openssl, csr, key-pair

I need to generate a certificate requests, with a specific field "Email". I've created a configuration file to generate my request, but I can't find a way to have this "non-standard" field in my CSR.

Here is my command line
`openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -noenc -pubkey -config config_file.cnf -keyout my_key.key -out my_csr.csr`

My config file content :

```
 [ req ]
 default_bits           = 2048
 prompt                 = no
 distinguished_name     = req_distinguished_name

 [ req_distinguished_name ]
 CN=XXXXXXX
 OU=XXXXXXX
 O=XXXXXXX
 L=XXXXXXX
 ST=XXXXXXX
 C=XXXXXXX
 subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
 subjectAltName=XXXXXXX
 keyUsage=digitalSignature
 extendedKeyUsage=clientAuth
 Email=mycustomemail@mycompany.com
```

With this configuration, I get the following error:

```
x509 certificate routines:X509_NAME_ENTRY_create_by_txt:invalid field name:../crypto/x509/x509name.c:249:name=Email
```

I know that there is an "emailAddress" field but it's not what I am asked.

I've tried to set the field in a "req_extensions", but without success.

I've also tried using OIDs (though I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do), but when look at the content of the CSR file (with `openssl req -text -in my_csr.csr`), I see the numbers associated with the OID and not the field name.